# Why is using wristlock throws so frowned upon in BJJ even though they are not illegal?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, throwing, hapkido, wrist-lock

I am a Blue Belt in BJJ and High-Green Belt in Hapkido, and recently I have been trying to integrate some throws that require manipulating the wrist (Outside Wrist Throw). This technique is from Hapkido and Aikido, and to me, I think it's a great idea as soon as someone grabs your lapel.

Well, I can't say people love it. But instead of accepting the technique, it seems as if people see it as cheating or unsportsmanlike. Why is that? The wrist is a joint like many others we attack in BJJ. And there is no striking involved either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, you need to ask your instructors and senior students about anything you see them turning their noses up to. Do this reflexively. Always ask why.

If they have no good answer for you, other than that they just don't do it, then that's your answer. Otherwise, this is the sort of question that will lead to a much better understanding of Brazilian Jiujitsu, because it could reveal something to you that you hadn't considered before.

Wrist locks and wrist take-downs are allowed in most BJJ competitions, with restrictions on children and for some belt ranks (typically not allowed until purple belt).

Wrist locks are in the official Gracie Jiujitsu syllabus, also. They appear in its classical self-defense drill sets. And there are some BJJ black belts who specialize in it and even put on workshops detailing wrist locks in BJJ.

If wrist techniques are legal to do and part of the art, then why would some BJJ people be uncomfortable with them?

One answer is that some people have never seen them, because they either do a sport version of BJJ, or they just haven't reached the rank where wrist locks are introduced. Naturally, they're not going to know what to do right away when you do your wrist lock on them. It might take your instructor stopping class to demo what to do in this case. Then after that, you might find your wrist lock becomes ineffective on others in your class.

In sport BJJ, wrist techniques are considered "low percentage" and may be excluded from practice altogether from a particular school. In other words, they're risky to do and put you in jeopardy of losing your positional advantage or getting submitted.

That being said, even if you do a self-defense based version of BJJ, you might find that your instructors are reluctant to use wrist manipulation. There are good reasons for that.

In the case of the Hapkido "outside wrist throw" that you mentioned (which I think is the same as the Aikido "kote-gaeshi" technique more or less), there are many ways this can go wrong for you. First, realize that someone who is fighting you isn't going to give you their wrists. In fact, the hands are typically the fastest moving body part on your opponent. They flail around so fast your eyes can't even see them. So if you're actively targeting them, trying to capture them and then do your wrist lock throw, you're likely going to fail miserably. You'll miss.

Instead, one of the principles of BJJ is to concentrate on the body first during a take-down, not on the extremities. The body (torso) is the slowest part of your opponent. That's why BJJ is so successful at diving under punches and doing a two-arm grab of the torso before the take-down. Even if you end up eating that punch, you still find yourself holding on to that torso, which allows you to take your opponent down and win the fight on the ground.

Second, the way this wrist throw is done, you typically have to get some distance between you and your opponent, and turn perpendicular to your opponent or turn your back against your opponent while applying force to the hand and wrist. This is problematic for you.

Getting distance implies you were close to your opponent already and then got out of there. There are easier ways of taking him down if you managed to get close. You just lost that advantage if you broke away. And you took extra time to get that distance, during which time your opponent can follow you and take you down. Also, at this distance, you're vulnerable to being struck with punches and kicks (and your opponent has a free arm and two free legs). BJJ likes to quickly get in and control the torso, because in that short distance, your opponent can't generate as much power in his strikes.

If you never got close in the first place prior to performing the wrist lock, then see my first point, above: People don't just let you grab their flailing wrists, unless you get lucky, but luck isn't something you should train to rely on.

Also, turning your body perpendicular to your opponent like this technique does means you are opening yourself up to being taken down. It's not a solid, defensive stance.

And using both of your hands to apply the wrist lock throw means both of your arms are busy doing something, while only one of his arms is captured. If you're doing the math, that means he has one more arm than you do free. Those are bad odds. And as I mentioned before, he still has the ability to kick and punch you, whereas your arms are tied up trying to do a wrist throw, unable to guard and block.

There are many Hapkido and Aikido people that just cringed upon reading that, I'll bet. They're recalling all of the times it worked for them in class, (typically against lapel grabs from stiff-armed people who are told to keep holding onto that lapel).

The key thing to realize is that these arts don't typically involve actively resisting opponents. When that element (sparring) is added, these wrist throws are almost never done. People don't let you take their wrists without punching or kicking the crap out of you, basically.

All that being said, do a Youtube search for "BJJ wrist locks". You might be surprised by what you see. There are a lot of videos showing them. But pay attention to the fact that none of them look anything like the outside wrist throw like you mentioned. Instead, they tend to be done from very close in when it's safe for them to do so.

BJJ people can be very sneaky about their wrist locks. You might not see them unless someone pointed it out. It's not that they're illegal moves, so people are trying to disguise them. No, they're all perfectly legal moves in BJJ. It's just that the wrist lock is generally not the only thing they have going on in the technique. It's like a cherry on top or the icing on the cake. It can and has been used to tap opponents, but it's most often used transitionally, to move into a better position.

It's probably something you should work on at black belt level. Until then, you might want to stick with the things your system is trying to teach you.

As for other techniques which come from other martial arts styles, besides wrist locks, this depends on the school and the instructor. People are there to learn BJJ, and so if you come into the school with stuff from other martial arts, it might be seen as, "That's nice, now how about you concentrate on learning what you're here to learn?" *(But definitely follow-up on it with your instructor asking him why those techniques are frowned upon.)*

The BJJ schools I've been to have all seemed to welcome other outside martial arts techniques. For example, one school I visited had a high ranking Judo student. So the 3rd degree black belt instructor asked the Judo student to show the class the proper way to throw. And apparently this was a regular part of their class, to ask her for correction on their throws.

I've seen other BJJ schools that have ex-wrestlers, muay-thai people, boxers, and kali people who demonstrate their stuff for the class. In general, it's a small part of the class, but the instructors welcome it.

The etiquette is very important, though. You can't just yell, "Hey everyone, look at me. I'm going to show you this cool Hapkido technique." Instead, it has to be something the instructor has seen you do before, asked you about, and had a chance to test you with it. Then in class, if he sees merit to the technique and thinks you're particularly good at it, he might turn to you and ask you to demonstrate it. Otherwise, it's best to keep it to yourself in class and work on it only when you're rolling outside of class time.

My perspective anyway. For what it's worth.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Very detailed answer. I appreciate this. The Outside Wrist Throw wouldn't work for the reason you stated. No one will just give their wrist, but, the times I have executed have been from a low lapel grip (about chest-height) while still standing up. It's basically the same idea as someone pushing you or shoving you, only their hand is on your chest long enough for you to grab it. This is what had me wondering the most about this. Why havent enough people been attacking that grip?

Comment: The reason you're able to get it from a lapel grab in class (not in competition, right?), is because people are more relaxed there and are working on what they've been told to work on. They're not expecting it. And most of the colored ranks haven't even seen it before. You're right to at least try it every now and then. Your classmates will improve their grip and strategy because of it. Just realize, though, that at some point this will stop working for you, and you'll find that it will actually cause you more grief than you want later on. So you'll probably abandon it eventually.

Comment: I definitely recommend getting your instructor in on it. Maybe ask him after class or during question & answer time in class (if you guys do that) if there's something wrong with doing what you're doing. If you can successfully take someone down from a lapel grab using it, then that says your classmates haven't been taught it and don't know to protect against it. It also says their grip needs to be more nuanced for the real world. It's a perfect setup for your instructor to step in and demonstrate to the class what you're doing, what to do to prevent it, and how to use it against you.

Comment: I would argue Aikido itself is a "low percentage" martial art.

Comment: @Tom I would tend to agree. I go over the strengths and weaknesses of Aikido here: http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/what-are-the-main-uses-of-aikido-in-self-defense/4733#4733

Comment: Good answer, but should really mention the possibility of injury to an unprepared uke too. (as the other two answers do)

Comment: Aikido aside, are wristlocks really seen in BJJ as low-percentage? I'm not sure I think that's true, or if I know exactly why BJJ doesn't prioritize them. I certainly think wrist locks (but not usually wristlock *throws*) are fine techniques in some scenarios.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann I suppose anything can become your bread and butter and can be turned into a high percentage technique if you train it enough. It may just be that most people haven't trained it enough to be good at it, and maybe that's why it's low percentage for most people. Lots of BJJ black belts have made an effort to train wrist locks to a high degree of reliability. But then, maybe that's only because all their other stuff is good enough that they can deliver wrist locks reliably or know which situations are optimal for wrist locks and which aren't. You have to talk with them.

Comment: @SteveWeigand There are a lot of positions in BJJ where you have a limb totally isolated, but they are able to defend the submission by positioning themselves in some way.  In these cases, a wrist lock is often available, and is very high percentage because the limb is already isolated.

Comment: These explanations all seem very biased against "wrist lock" techniques in general.  There is a lot more to wrist manipulation than is suggested here.  The strength of two arms against one on a wrist joint can be very effective and quickly leave an opponent too off balance to do anything let alone punch or grab.  That makes good odds does it not?  The issues you suggest here (risk of breaking bone, not working against resisting attacker) are beginner problems.  If you are wearing clothing and it gets grabbed wrist locks are valuable tools.

Comment: @HuwEvans What you said is all good in theory. As I point out, it's rarely done in competition. To be in a position where you can take time out to crank on a wrist, you first need to be really good in everything else. Which I think is why this is less common in colored belts rather than the black belt ranks in BJJ. In Tomiki aikido and Hapkido competition, too, we don't see a lot of successful wrist manipulation, especially not the wrist lock throw. It's trickier than it appears. And just because you have the wrist by two hands, it doesn't mean you will very quickly submit your opponent.

Comment: What do you mean "take time out to crank a wrist?" That's just not how it works.  They grab your clothing and push/pull and you use that movement.  If it doesn't work you do something else but you are hardly "taking time out" to do it.  You seem to imply that the technique has no effect at all if it doesn't threaten to break the wrist and put them on the floor, but that's not true.  It will always either destablise the attacker or pin them in place.  You don't grab the wrist and crank.  You let them give you the wrist.  Just like you don't choose to strangle, you wait for the opportunity.

Comment: There are a number of scenarios where the wrist can be manipulated. One is the lapel grab that you described. The other is the case BJJ tends to use it in, which is when you've established position on the ground and have control over your opponent. Then you're in a position to apply the wrist crank, but it usually isn't immediate and requires a struggle even if you have two hands cranking on his wrist. The lapel grab to outer wrist lock throw is something else. But it too has this problem. All it takes is for someone to make a fist for that wrist lock to be thwarted....

Comment: ... Making a tight lapel grab thwarts the wrist lock. In competition, that's going to be the problem with the standing lapel grab to outer wrist lock throw defense. You won't see flimsy grips in competition, just in class. Same goes for real life. What I'm saying is that it's more likely than you might think that you're going to have to struggle even with two handed wrist locks. But then, you can always sense that it's not working out and let go quickly. I'm just saying be conscious of that fact. Struggling with this while not having secured your opponent is a bad idea.

Comment: @HuwEvans If you're so sure in your wristlock technique in the context of BJJ, then go try it out. Most BJJ schools offer a handful of free classes and they'll be happy to give you a blue or purple belt to try your wrist manipulations on.

Comment: They might or might not. Ill look into it.

Answer (score 8):

Most throws in BJJ descend from western wrestling, or Judo.  In both of these arts, the focus is on taking the opponents balance.  Resisting one of these throws does not matter much:  if someone is good, you can strain all you like against their seio nage, but basic physics cannot be violated, and if your balance is taken you will end up safely thrown to your back.

Kote-gaeshi relies on a different principle:  uke falls down because they have to fall down to avoid having their wrist broken.

There is a culture in BJJ of applying submissions slowly enough that your opponent can tap without injury.  Kote-gaeshi violates this expectation:  you apply a submission quickly to provoke a response other than tapping.

This idea is probably foreign to most BJJ players.  They see you as cranking a low percentage submission, and trying to break their wrist.  To them, this technique is a lot like cranking on an armbar - it makes you a dick.

If you want to start training this technique, it needs to be introduced to your training partners carefully.  They need to learn the ukemi, or they are at risk of injury.  They need to know what you are going for, so they do not see it as irresponsibly dangerous.

Follow the rules of your academy.  If heel hooks are banned, do not use them.  If wrist locks are banned, do not use them.  You can try to make an argument for a rule change, but I would advise against "civil disobedience" in a context where people's joints are on the line.

If you get permission to experiment with kote-gaeshi, I would ask some of your friends to drill it with you first.  Learn the ukemi together.  When you play standup, only go for wristlocks with those people you have drilled with.  You might even give them a heads up that you are going to try and attempt them during the practice.

Eventually, if you have a lot of success, and there are no injuries,  you might find that the culture of your academy grows to accept these as a normal part of training.

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me.  You can do a wrist lock slowly and still get someone to fall.  It's about technique not speed.

Comment: @HuwEvans  If you think that you can reliably "take someones balance" with the wristlock, in a technical way, which does not put the opponent in danger, then I would ask you to film some sparring matches and put the results on my other question...

Comment: It's actually something I've been meaning to do for a while.  This is not the first time I have come across this misconception.  I'll do it when I can but it's not going to be soon.  It's hard for me to get to training at the moment.

Comment: Question:  if the wristlock throw is about taking balance, and not about avoiding injury, then why do you need to bend the wrist?  Could you not throw someone with the same mechanics just by holding their wrist without bending it?

Comment: Shorinji kempo has an advanced technique called ippon seo nage (not to be confused with the judo technique) which does just this.  However it is much more difficult than an actual wrist lock so much so that I would never try to use this in a fight, but some people who are better than me might.  The technique involves taking hold of the wrist and then throwing the opponent over your shoulder while applying an arm bar.  The reason you lock the wrist is that you can take advantage of some ways that the arm will not move.  ie, you lock the wrist and the elbow together to apply leverage.

Comment: This video shows several different ways of doing the wrist-lock called kote gaeshi in most jujutsu styles.  (we call it gyaku gote) Notice that some of the methods cause pain while others are purely balance based.  https://youtu.be/qpPFwBdyMZg I know it's not a sparring video but I doubt you would be able to appreciate what was happening if (when) I post a sparing video without having seen this first.

Comment: @HuwEvans I believe that in each case, if uke was willing to have his wrist broken, he would not have to move.

Comment: That is not the case.  Some of these methods apply no pain and little pressure the the wrist.  take the one at 2:03 for example.  There is no risk of breaking the wrist whatsoever here.  He is just being pulled along by clever placement of the elbow.

Comment: The one at 2:03 seems fake to me.  It seems to operate on the same principle as no touch throws.  It is probably difficult to continue this discussion without actually meeting in person.

Comment: I don't know about these 'know touch throws'.  That sounds unlikely to work.  However I know this is real, because I can do this particular one myself.  I could even show you how to do it given time.  it seems that you are not yet familiar enough with wrist-locks to understand what can be done.  They are more versatile then you think.

Comment: http://www.page.sannet.ne.jp/unix/md/_eng/hiden/hiden-e.pdf This link explains how to do this kind of technique.  It's about adding momentum or angular momentum to the push or pull or twist of an attack to leave the attacker off balance.  These are almost exclusively defensive techniques for this reason.

Comment: @HuwEvans  Out of curiosity, why do you think that this sort of technique is absent from Judo, Wrestling, Bjj, Sambo, and other grappling arts?  Without torquing the wrist, it would seem to not violate any rules.   The only arts advocating such techniques seem not to spar with fully resisting opponents.   Until I feel it myself, I will have to maintain my scepticism.

Comment: There are several reasons.  It WAS in traditional jujutsu but was taken out of Judo for saftey reasons.  You CAN break the elbow if you get it wrong (that would go before the wrist joint I think).  So far as I know it is legal in Sambo and BJJ but you have to learn it against a non resisting partner before  you can do it against a resisting one.  There is no motivation in a combat sport to allow your friend to learn this.  wrestling + sambo they tend not to wear much.  The opportunities for most of these kind of techniques are when your clothing is grabbed.

Comment: If you want to have this done so you can feel it then go to ANY WSKO dojo/doin.  The organisation has it's flaws, but the techniques work and any instructor could demonstrate it on you.

Comment: @HuwEvans  Unfortunately, it would seem that the nearest WSKO school is several hundred miles away from me.  In any event, I think the burden of proof is on those making extraordinary claims.  There are ample forums to prove the efficacy of these techniques.  Simply enroll in BJJ, Judo, or Sambo tournaments locally, in the white belt division, and see if you can score such a takedown.  This would be a huge service to your art.

Comment: Also, in Sambo they wear gi tops, so there are plenty of grips to attack.

Comment: Why? No-one in kempo cares about competitions.  SK has had people enter MMA and japanese open competitions.  Hiroshi Aosaka for example entered (and won) many competitions.  To me this is just the propagation of ignorance I don't see how me entering a competition of any kind would help.

Comment: @HuwEvans Without a competition, there is no way to know what works and what does not work.  If you claim that you can use these techniques on resisting opponents, then the only way to back up that claim is to do so publically.  This is the definition of a competition.  By saying no one in kempo cares about competitions, you are saying no one cares about proving the efficacy of their techniques.  Best of luck in your martial arts journey.

Comment: That is Hiroshi Aosaka's attitude, so he went into some competitions.  The founder (his teacher) disagreed but let him enter because at least this way he wasn't beating up the other students.  We DO have competitions inside Shorinji Kempo (It's not a big part of the style though) but you don't catch me saying BJJ or Thai Boxing doesn't work because they would loose this competition.  This is just becoming an argument about how martial arts advertise and what philosophy they have.  Not what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Also note that historically martial arts involving wrist locks have been all but stamped out in japan as part of the american military rule and prior as part of the nationalist movement.  In china the cultural revolution similarly removed many martial styles from existence.  The martial arts that survived this were basically those that could claim to be something else.  Both in china and in japan.  So we have Aikido, shinto ryu and shorinji kempo (all small religious groups) we have judo and BJJ a judo derivative which are sports we have the western styles like boxing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34163/discussion-between-steven-gubkin-and-huw-evans).

Answer (score 7):

I find wristlock throws to sometimes be frowned upon because they are somewhat dangerous due to the speed with which they must be applied to be successful, and their unfamiliarity.

Unfamiliarity can be fixed, just like leglocks are currently undergoing a normalization process in the community, or like wristlocks-as-a-submission are better recognized in BJJ. Recognize that with familiarity comes defenses and counters--in fact, showing someone how to avoid, defend, roll out of, and counter your wristlock throw is probably the fastest way to getting them to accept it. (And your technique will improve too!)

The fact that a wristlock throw has to be executed fast is tough to fix. People are going to be justifiably angry if you crank their joint in order to throw them, whether you're doing *kotegaeshi* or a Kimura-ripping *sumi gaeshi* or a *waki-gatame*. It's impolite in BJJ to apply submissions fast with the intent to make the opponent move instead of tap.

Comment: BJJ has evolved probably ten-fold since the early days of Gracie Jiu Jitsu. And it has grown that much more due to the influence of other arts. Like you said, leglocks were a big no-no. Now they're not. Then the focus shifted to slicers. Now, not so much. I understand a violent change of direction on the wrist hurts, but it can be trained

Answer (score -1):

Wrist locks are the new leg locks. Close-minded know-it-alls sometimes wear black belts:) Experiment for yourself. Stay open-minded and free. Have no style but your own - if that appeals to you. They used to frown on wrestling, leg locks, judo, striking and everything else they aren’t familiar with. I know. I was there. And, I used wristlocks to high percentage levels. When you figure out how to apply them in your JJ game, be really careful, and never “snap”. Keep it slow and steady. The wrist does break. If there’s a good reason to not do it… it’s because it’s dangerous like a heel hook. Luckily, most people are doing the aikido style wrist folding, and abandon that as useless. It’s not totally a bad thing. I’ve felt a wrist break in my hands. I don’t want to feel that ever again. Oh, and, starting to do a wrist-lock is a great set-up to more standard moves, when they pull away. Be sure to integrate.

Comment: If you pull off wrist-lock **throws** (which the question is about) with high percentage in actual BJJ competition I'd like to see footage and a detailed description of the technique, as this is completely unheard of as far as I am aware. We are not speaking about some small dojo training in some shady style in a compliant fashion here but full-resistance BJJ competition.